# Result of a program in C++ including global and local variables

Tags: c++

Im given the following code in the language C++:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num1(1);
int num2(2);

int foo1(int val) {
  val = val + 1;
  return val;
}

int foo2(int& val) {
  val = val + 1;
  num1 = num2 + 1;
  return val - 1;
}

int foo3(int& val) {
  int num2(2);
  num2 = num2 + 1;
  return foo1(3*num1) + foo2(val) ;
}

int main() {
  int num1(3);
  cout << "Resultat 1: " << foo3(num1) << endl;
  cout << "Resultat 2: " << num1 << endl;
  cout << "Resultat 3: " << num2 << endl;
}
```

And the question I have to answer is what the program will display. I'm pretty confused, because there are global and local variables with the same name, and I don't now how to treat this ambiguity. What will be the answer? As I'm pretty new in programming, please give some explanations.

Ps: Why don't we have to write a

```
return 0;
```

at the end of the main?

Edit: I'm sorry that my question doesn't seem to be suitable for this forum; I'm new here. Following the suggestions in the comments I compiled it and got :

```
Resultat 1: 7
Resultat 2: 4
Resultat 3: 2
```

I think I understand what happens; the local variable and the the global variable are treated as different variables; at least the result would make sense in that manner. Is this true? How to explain this, i.e. why isn't this an ambiguity for the compiler?

I should add that the exercise is from an exam on paper, so actually one couldn't simply compile the program.

If the question is still not appropriate, please leave a comment and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: You can just [compile and run it yourself](http://ideone.com/7TNYhe) to see what happens, then maybe work backwards so that you understand what's going on.

Comment: If you really want to understand how a piece of code is working then you should step through the code with your debugger.  This will let you see what is going on for each line of your program.

Comment: Wo do not have to write a `return 0` in `main` because it is unnessesary in C++.

Comment: Voted to close because since the poster seems uninterested in building and running the program, neither should anyone else.

Comment: "I'm pretty confused..." yes, that's the point of the exercise. You have to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "parts in the program" where a variable is valid is called the variable scope. 
C++ is flexible and allows for variable overriding.

here is some explanations, but ultimately you have to play with it yourself to find out.

this is best shown in example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int num1(1); //this is global scope
int num2(2); //so is this
//global variables are available inside all functions including main


int foo1(int val) {  //num1 and num2 are available here
  val = val + 1;  //val is a parameter passed by value. it is just a copy
  //what you do to val here will not stick to the variable that was passed in
  return val;
}

int foo2(int& val) {
  val = val + 1;   //val is a parameter passed by reference, what you do to it here will stick
  num1 = num2 + 1; // global variables are available to be manipulated
 // (changes will stick because there is no copy in function)

  return val - 1;   //(val-1) is a temporary value (rvalue), it does not affect value of val;
}

//val is not available here, because it is only a function parameter valid in the bodies of foo1,foo2 and foo3.

int foo3(int& val) { //val is an integer again passed by reference, means changing it will change the variable that was sent to this function.
  int num2(2); //this is a variable declared in the scope of this function, 
 //it is only available in this function, when this function returns
 //then num2 is destroyed.

 //this is generally not considered good practice, because you are masking 
 //a global variable, from now on, num2 refers to the local copy
 //if you want the global num2 you have to use ::num2 

  num2 = num2 + 1; //whatever we do to num2 is for the local copy only
 //becuase we overrode the name.(usually bad idea)

  return foo1(3*num1) + foo2(val) ; 
}

int main() {
 //global num1 is available here 

  int num1(3); //here is another example of overriding a global variable. 

  //at this point num1 no longer refers to the global variable,
  // instead it refers to the local variable declared in main. 
  //if you want global variable num1 you should use ::num1

  cout << "Resultat 1: " << foo3(num1) << endl;  //passes the local variable num1 by reference. it will take the name "value" inside foo3
  cout << "Resultat 2: " << num1 << endl;
  cout << "Resultat 3: " << num2 << endl;
}
```

There is another very important lesson to be learned here: pass by value and pass by reference semantics. 
a function that takes a parameter by value only receives a copy. subsequent changes to that variable inside the function body will not affect the parameter that was passed in.

in contrast, a function that takes a parameter by reference, will receive a "reference to the variable" which allows it to modify the variable directly.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question, I understand it now. +1

Comment: There is so much that is difficult to explain everything written. and it is much more difficult to understand just by reading the solution over. you should go play with your compiler and try to understand what is happening to every variable in every step of the way. better yet, use a debugger like gdb. If you can not justify to yourself why a variable has a value that it does, then come back and read my comments

Comment: you should first test foo1 and foo2 in isolation and completely understand what they are doing. Then go for foo3